# Results extraction for a dynamic result using selenium webdriver

Tags: search, dynamic, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

I am working on application, were I need to provide search criteria available in a database and no. of results displayed are not equal every time.

For Ex: Search with 1234 , it may display 4 results today and 3 results next day, so my requirements are below:

1. How to provide the search criteria dynamically for under search(BDD).
2. How to display the results in console for the given input.
3. And I want to display the results and validate by clicking on each and every result.

Note: App is developed using Angular JS. I have tried using WebElement List but it is not extracting for dynamic search result for the drop down only looking in the page.

Also anyone can suggest how to provide search result under Behavioral Driven Development.

Please suggest using Selenium Commands.

Thanks for all your support and co-operations.